# How to remove XP and install Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, backup, windows-xp

I'm writing this for my friend, because he asked me 'cause my english is better than his. He wants to remove xp from his system, and install ubuntu 12.04. He has a lot of data which he would like to copy. He has no USB-Stick only a CD-Drive. His system is p3 with 1 gigabyte RAM and AGP video card. He wants to know how to get his data, and how to backup the software and then install ubuntu.

Thanks for help

Comment: just a note->The softwares backed up in windows are of no use in linux. :)

Comment: for backing up data he could use some kind of free cloud storage ,it all depends on the size of the important data.I'd suggest look at Google Drive or Dropbox

Comment: I know just in case he has any documents, and those can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to backup all your data.   Organize you data all at one location (folder).  Windows XP Professional, Backup utility is installed by default, which is very helpful to create a backup copy of your important files.

```
Click Start  >  All Programs  >  Accessories  >  System Tools  >  Backup
```

Click Next and then choose ***Back up Files and Settings***

Click all the folders you want to backup.

Choose the backup type, Destination and Name

Windows XP does not support writing the backup file to a CD directly, so create the backup file in the same hard disk and burn it in a CD or DVD.

Go to the Ubuntu website to download Ubuntu.  Choose the [32bit](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) version. Burn the ISO to a CD.  Since you have Windows XP, you can use [Free ISO Burner](http://www.freeisoburner.com/) , once that is done, boot from the newly created CD, make sure that you system is set to boot from CD.

When you get to the Installation Type screen, choose erase and install.

[image]

Continue the installation following the on screen instructions.

Comment: i saw yesterday from my freind account, and i try thank you