# How to install Ubuntu13.04 with windows xp & remove windows xp?

Tags: installation

I want install Ubuntu13.04 from dvd. Is it possible without current windows xp os? If yes Please tell me the procedure in steps. If it is not possible then I will have to first install Ubuntu13.04 & uninstall windows xp professional. In this case  please tell procedure in steps

Answer (score 1):

Installing any recent version of Ubuntu  is pretty much the same and there are plenty of tutorials out there.

If you have a current OS, XP or anything else, you can use [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156672/how-to-remove-xp-and-install-ubuntu) Use the steps given

If you do not have a current OS, you can just boot the system from your Ubuntu DVD and follow this [installation guide](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Installing-Ubuntu-13-04-348582.shtml).

Comment: +1 as the first guide linked first step is to backup data.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu along side an existing Windows XP. I doesn't matter if it is a recent Version or not. Or you can overwrite the current OS while installing Ubuntu.

I've found the official step-by-step [instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest) provided by ubuntu.com to be pretty good.